# Get unique values and their counts in a column

Tags: text-processing

I have a column like this.

```
Streptococcus
Ecoli
Bcoli
Ecoli
streptococcus
Streptococcus
Mycobacterium
Ecoli
```

I want a file like this (which includes all unique values and their corresponding counts)

```
Streptococcus 3
Ecoli 3
Bcoli 1
Mycobacterium 1
```

Can anyone please help in getting it in ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Which language? shell, c, python.. any?

Answer (score 2):

Using sort and uniq,

```
$ sort f | uniq -ci | awk '{print $2,$1}'
Bcoli 1
Ecoli 3
Mycobacterium 1
streptococcus 3
```

Comment: Or you can simply pass -i option to uniq to ignore case if needed. It would be uniq -ci.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming each item appears on another line, here is a python solution. Of course you can write the result to a file instead of printing it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sourcefile = "/path/to/sourcefile"

with open(sourcefile, "r") as germ:
    germ = [item.lower().replace("\n", "") for item in germ.readlines()]
for item in sorted(set(germ)):
    print item.title(), germ.count(item)
```

it gives:

```
Bcoli 1
Ecoli 3
Mycobacterium 1
Streptococcus 3
```

**To use it**

paste the code above in an empty textfile, save it as `get_uniques.py`, make it executable (for convenience reasons, so you don't need to type the language if you run it) and run it in a terminal window by the command:

```
/path/to/get_uniques.py
```

**In case you'd like to write it to a file directly**

Use the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
sourcefile = "/path/to/sourcefile"
destfile = "/path/to/destinationfile"

with open(sourcefile, "r") as germ:
    germ = [item.lower().replace("\n", "") for item in  germ.readlines()]
with open(destfile, "wt") as germcount:
    for item in sorted(set(germ)):
        germcount.write(item.title()+" "+str(germ.count(item))+"\n")
```

Comment: you don't need to make the .py file executable. Just running `python file.py` is enough. And also don't give the short form of input file path in `.py` file. Short form means `~/Desktop`. If you do like so then it gives an error. So path should be in expanded form.