# replace newline with tab at a specific location

Tags: location

I have a file like this.

```
M00425_ght_cgd2_2212_B_0_2 (newline)
ATGCCGTTAGAGCTAG
M00425_ght_cgd2_2213_B_0_3_1 (newline)
GTACATTGACATAGAGTACATAGCGA
```

I want a file like this:

```
M00425_ght_cgd2_2212_B_0_2(tab)ATGCCGTTAGAGCTAG
M00425_ght_cgd2_2213_B_0_3_1(tab)GTACATTGACATAGAGTACATAGCGA
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: I noticed you have an other question "open" (as "Unanswered") http://askubuntu.com/questions/491919/get-unique-values-and-their-counts-in-a-column didn't one of the answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Simple `sed` command:

```
sed '$!N;s/\n/\t/' inputfile.txt > outputfile.txt
```

Which means join every pair of lines with a Tab delimiter.

This command joins two consecutive lines with the `N` command. They get joined with a `\n` character between them. The substitute command replaces this newline with a tab, thus joining every pair of lines with a Tab delimiter.

Also that looks like this `sed '/$/N;s/\n/\t/' inputfile.txt` command.

IF your file contains empty lines you can first delete all that lines by using below `sed` command:

```
sed -i '/^$/d' inputfile.txt
```

Comment: This works perfectly *if* you can be sure there is nowhere a whiteline between the pairs, and the first line is sure not to be a whiteline.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Jacob's answer, but different enough that I thought it warranted mention.  Instead of searching for the presence of a string, you could check if the line contained characters other than "GACT".

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    if len(lines[i].strip('GACT\n'))>0:
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace('\n','\t')
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

If your file does not meet the requirements of unique identifiers in the replacement lines, you can also make a different assumption.  The following assumes that for every odd numbered line you want to replace the newline with a tab, and for every even numbered line you do not.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

with open('input.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(lines)):
    if i/2==i/2.0:
        lines[i] = lines[i].replace('\n','\t')
with open('output.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

You could save these as, for example, `lines2tabs.py` then navigate to the directory in a terminal using `cd` and run it using `python lines2tabs.py`.  Note that you'll have to change `input.txt` to the name of your file.